# Is this data appropriate for a 2-way ANOVA? If not is there a non-parametric alternative?

Tags: anova, nonparametric, residuals, normality-assumption

I'm measuring the effect of tree Genus and location on % change in diameter at breast height of trees (converted to 0-100 rather than a %). I underwent a 2-way ANOVA using the following code:

```
swp_model <- lm(percentage ~ Species + Ward + Species : Ward, data = trees)
```

However, I was diagnosing the model and was unsure whether these results might indicate a non-parametric test would be better suited: [image]

[image]

[image]

The data has a strong positive skew as seen here:
[image]

I underwent a few transformations of the percentage variable to see if that made the data a better fit for the test. Square rooting seemed to have the best result, as this mostly fixed the normal probability assumption, but not the other two. At this stage would it be better to use a non-parametric test for this data? If so, which would be the most appropriate?